# Laravel 4 change form open with if else statement

Tags: forms, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel and trying some stuff out. Hope you guys can point me in the right direction.

I have a form to add categories on a the page with the overview of all the categories. Now I'm routing to the same page when you want to add or edit a category. Problem is, I want the normal add form to show when the url is category/add and when the url is category/edit/id I want it to show the form to edit (with form model binding). I placed the code in an if else statement, but it always shows the edit form, therefore if I want to add a new category on the url categories I get an error because it's the edit form.

**Here's the code in the index.bade.php:**

```
@if(Request::url() === 'categories' )
   {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'category/add', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}
@else
  {{ Form::model($category, array(
     'url' => 'category/edit/'.$category->id , 
     $category->id, 
     'class' => 'form-horizontal')) 
  }}
@endif
```

**My controller:**

```
public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::get();
        $category = new Category();
        View::share('title', 'Mini Blog - Categories');

        $view = View::make('category.index')->with('category', $category);
        $view->categories = $categories;
        return $view;
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $categories = Category::get();
        $category = Category::find($id);
        View::share('title', 'Mini Blog - Edit category');
        return View::make('category.index')->with(array('category' => $category, 'categories' => $categories));

    }
```

Is this the way to go? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking the URL I suggest you depend on the model variable. Ever Eloquent model has a property `exists` that tells you if the model has been loaded from the DB or it's a new instance.

```
@if( ! $category->exists)
   {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'category/add', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}
@else
   {{ Form::model($category, array(
       'url' => 'category/edit/'.$category->id , 
       $category->id, 
       'class' => 'form-horizontal')) 
   }}
@endif
```

Actually you can use `Form::model` with an empty model as well, so you should be able to reduce it to this:

```
{{ Form::model($category, array(
    'url' => ($category->exists ? 'category/edit/'.$category->id : 'category/add'),
    'class' => 'form-horizontal')) 
}}
```

Comment: Thank you sooooo much! You're a lifesaver! I'll never forget it now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much better way.

In your controller do this:

```
    public function create()
    {
        return View::make('create');
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        return View::make('edit')->withId($id);
    }
```

Then in your views you have

**Create.blade.php**

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'category/add', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}
    @include ('form')
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**Edit.blade.php**

```
{{ Form::model($category, array('url' => 'category/edit/'.$category->id, category->id, 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}
    @include ('form')
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**Form.blade.php**

```
   //Put your HTML form stuff here
```

Comment: But then there is a different view for the edit and add, I want them both in the index. I updated my question with my controller as is. Thanks for helping me out!